# Passing an object into a method in s:property

Tags: jsp, struts2

I'm trying to pass an object from s:iterator into a method defined in my action, but for some reason struts2 is only passing a null object.

My code looks like:

```
<s:iterator value="#currentPriceList.discounts" var="currentDiscount">
    <s:property value="discountLine(#currentDiscount)" /><br />
</s:iterator>
```

This function doesn't call the discountLine method at all.

I do get the correct values when I change this to something like:

```
<s:iterator value="#currentPriceList.discounts" var="currentDiscount">
    <s:property value="#currentDiscount.appliesTo" />
</s:iterator>
```

I also get the correct behavior when I pass a field from currentDiscount into the method.

```
<s:iterator value="#currentPriceList.discounts" var="currentDiscount">
    <s:property value="displaySomeText(#currentDiscount.appliesTo)" />
</s:iterator>
```

So, how do I pass in the full currentDiscount object into a action method?

Update to the questions:

The output from `<s:property value="#currentDiscount.class"/>` is `com.acteva.model.wrapper.PriceListWrapper$Discounts`

The method signatures for the two called methods is:

```
public String discountLine(Discounts discount)
```

and

```
public String displaySomeText(String valueToDisplay)
```

Comment: hard to tell, you might have a type issue... does <s:property value="#currentDiscount.class"/> produce the type you expect for the method?

Comment: Can you post the method signature of both discountLine() and displaySomeText() ?

Comment: Thanks for looking.  I've updated the initial issue.